# transform:scale with iframe in Chrome

Tags: css, facebook, google-chrome

Don't know why but iframes lose quality with big transform:scale value in Chrome in last stable version (67). Do you know, is it bug or feature?
In other browsers it's OK.

In Chrome: [image]

In Chromium: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed nothing, but now it's OK. Seems just a bug.